# matlab crashes when using ocr function

Tags: matlab, ocr, tesseract

Here is a simple code snip, I want to recognize the Chinese characters in the picture:

```
img = imread('t_0001.png');
bimg = im2bw(img);
txt = ocr(bimg, 'Language', 'tessdata\chi_sim.traineddata');//crashes
%txt = ocr(bimg);//workes well
```

I am sure the picture file is intact and I have the right .traindata file, and it works well when using the default parameter(use English language), but when I switch to use Chinese, the program crashes and matlab exits.
I debugged the code and found that the problem lied in the following code(in ocr.m file):

```
[txt, ocrMetadata] = tesseractWrapper(tessOpts, Iu8, hasROI, roi, resetParameters);
```

it couldn't execute properly and caused the problem. But I don't have the source codes of the function and can't figure out why, does anybody have similar experience and have some tips?

Comment: Please share the error, so we can help you. If you want to see the source code of a MATLAB function, you use    edit tesseractWrapper.m

Comment: The problematic codes are exactly these three lines, no error information was showed. While debugging, when executed to '[txt, ocrMetadata] = tesseractWrapper(tessOpts, Iu8, hasROI, roi, resetParameters);' the program exits with matlab together...

Comment: It can have many reasons. I think your dataset has a problem.